# Boundary and interior of $\mathbb Q \times(\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q)$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

> I was wondering, what is the boundary and the interior $A=\mathbb Q \times ( \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q)$?

I have been discussing this problem with some classmates and we all have different answers, we are doubting between:

1) $ \text{int} (A) = \emptyset$, $\quad$
$\partial A = \mathbb R ^2$

2) $ \text{int} (A) = \emptyset$, $\quad$
$\partial A = \mathbb Q ^2$

But maybe both are incorrect.

Comment: $\partial A=\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Any neighborhood of every point in the plane meets both $A$ and $A^c$.